# how to stop execution of onclick when the page is actualised?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, onclick

i have a jsf projet and i am using  **menuitem** to navigate between pages .. i added ONCLICK to the menuitem because i need to do an action before directing the user to the page wanted ..... the problem is when the page that contain the ONCLICK when  is actualised the onclick are executed to. how to stop the execution of onclick in that case ?

```
<p:menuitem value="fotopage1"  styleClass="submenustyle" onclick="#{action.gotopage()}" outcome="/cuisson/page1.xhtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onclick` event you can only call a client side function, so it's no good here. Why it somewhat works I believe is not intended. From the PF user guide:

```
onclick: Javascript event handler for click event
```

But you can use an `actionListener` instead. Then the next problem will be that the actionListener will not fire when there is an outcome on the menuitem. This you can solve by using an `action` instead:

```
<p:menuitem value="fotopage1" styleClass="submenustyle" actionListener="#{bean.gotoPage}" action="/cuisson/page1.xhtml"/>
```